# How to process user command line input for Python bruteforce script with optparse?

Tags: python, ssh, ftp

I am attempting to create a script for bruteforcing SSH (and other protocols) as part of a project from what I have learned. This is only a portion of the code:

```
import optparse, sys, os

def main():
     parser = optparse.OptionParser()
     parser.add_option('-v', '--verbose', dest='verbose', help='Show output of program executing')
     parser.add_option('-u', '--username', dest='username', help='Provide a valid username for service/protocol being executed.')
     parser.add_option('-s', '--service', dest='service', help="Provide a service being attacked. Several protocols and services are supported.")
     parser.add_option('-p', '--password', dest='password', help='Provide a wordlist or directory to a wordlist')
     parser.add_option('-a', '--address', dest='address', help='Provide host address for specified service')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    man_options = ['username', 'password']
    for m in man_options:
        if not options.__dict__[m]:
            print R + "You have to specify a username AND a wordlist!" + W
            sys.exit()
```

I want to allow the user to pass the protocol they want to attack with the `-s` flag, following the protocol, such as `ssh`, `ftp`,  and etc.

This was my initial code that followed up:

```
if (options.service == 'ssh' or 'SSH') and (options.address is None):
    print R + "Please specify a host for SSH" + W
    sys.exit()
#else:
    # do the actual dictionary attack
```

Although that initially worked:

```
$ python script.py -u test -p test.txt -s ssh
Please specify a host for SSH
$ python script.py -u test -p test.txt -s ssh -a 123
$
```

Adding these lines of code for FTP lead to problems:

```
if (options.service == 'ftp' or 'FTP') and (options.address is None):
    print R + "Please specify a host for FTP" + W
    sys.exit()
```

As running the script leads to this:

```
$ python script.py -u test -p test.txt -s ftp
Please specify a host for SSH
```

How do I solve this problem? I have done quite some research on `optparse` and not much has helped me solved this problem. Thanks!

Comment: From the optparse documentation: "Deprecated since version 2.7: The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the argparse module."... it might be more worthwhile to start with argparse :)

Comment: Note also that `argparse` supports "required options", so you don't have to do that ugly `__dict__` stuff.  When you see something like that, you know there must be a better way ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll make the switch and ill see what happens then